# is there a way to configure pam file programmatically?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-20.04, pam

I created a pam authentication module which should load up after regular authentication. SO the step will be to open the necessary pam specific application say for example SSH, then I need to open SSHD file which is located in /etc/pam.d/sshd and add the line after the common auth i.e,

```
#common linux authentication
@include common-auth
#the line which i wanted to add after common auth
auth    required    2fa_test_pam.so
```

so that the pam module will load my authentication module whenever SSH is invoked. but the catch is I don't want to do it manually, so is there any way to add modules at specified place to pam files programmatically or with any shell commands?? am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What exactly do you want to automate, and why? For a quick and dirty update just run `cat` to create a new file with the contents you want, or create a simple `.deb` package which drops the file where you want it from its `postinstall`

Comment: like i told in the example after a certain line (it must be variable) the following line should be added

Comment: The point of `something.d` directories is that you can drop new files in there and remove them, manually or programmatically. Making changes to existing files is probably not a good tactic; regard the files as static and only check whether they exist or not.